# Python index/lineno for calling expr's ast with inspect

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, inspect

I am trying to get the caller expression's ast but the index/lineno of the frames seems off for multi-line expression.

```
class Foo:
    def fun(self, arg):
        stack = inspect.stack(100)
        frame = stack[1]

f = Foo()

# This works fine
ast = f.fun(1) 

# For some reason, the frame's index is pointing to the "+2" line instead of the closing ")" line
# I am hoping to capture the expression that makes the 'fun' function call

ast = f.fun(1
            + 2
            )
```

Appreciate any help or thought on this or how to deal with multi-line code frames..

Comment: What version of Python are you using? with 3.7.1 I see that the frame's line number for the second call points to the line with `ast = f.fun(1`

Comment: I am using 3.5.9...yeah, pointing to 'f.fun(1' is still better than pointing to '+2'